# What are your techniques of optimizing your code in c++?

Tags: c++, optimization

What are your techniques of optimizing your code in c++?

Comment: This is not an answer since it would be down-voted by the "premature-optimization is root of all evil"-guys: I write clean and straight-forward code but try to avoid things I know they are slow depending on the context (i.e. in some contexts I try to avoid new/delete in others not [depends how important performance is])

Comment: Read the stuff at following link http://www.agner.org/optimize/  Understand it, but realize you wont be able to do every single optimization mentioned, so don't try...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Write code
2. Profile code
3. Tweak performance hot spots
4. If still not fast enough, go to step 2

Answer (score 5):

1) Write the cleanest and most straightforward code I can.
2) Use a modern compiler with optimized settings.
3) Be done.

Optional:
4) If I think something is noticeably slow, profile my application.
5) Use my profile results to find out what's slow, and fix it.
6) Make sure it's still as clean and straightforward as possible.
7) Be done.

Comment: Of these, step six is (IMO) by far the most difficult.  Making heavily hand-optimized code clean and straightforward is astonishingly hard.  It's also tremendous fun though :-D

Comment: The number of times I have had to go past 3 is countable on my hands. -O4 is always nice. The a copy of Knuth on the shelf is often useful for picking the correct algorithm as the compiler can't do that and O(n.ln(n)) is always going to be better than o(n^2)

Comment: @Martin: not if the O(nlogn) is the average case, qsort vs bubble sort. numbers sorted in reverse order reduce qsort to O(n^2)......

Answer (score 2):

The most important technique is not optimising until you know it's a bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

Follow coding standards. Have a look at http://sourcemaking.com/

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with the question, does it?

Comment: Infact mate, it does. Whatever language you code in, if you get the basics right, your code will be optimized. Apart from that, each project has different optimization rules/techniques that you can only learn from experience, and not by simply asking questions ...

Comment: @Samnan: Your code will be optimized if you write it efficiently. Coding standards typically emphasize other qualities than performance. If you follow the "best practices" commonly found in Java, then your program is going to spend 95% of its time wading through endless layers of abstraction. It won't be fast, but it will follow a lot of people's guidelines.

Comment: Thanks jalf, I totally agree with your comments too. However, I only wanted to emphasize to the new guy that if he able to write neat and clean code initially, he will be able to optimize it more naturally later on. I have seen plenty of 'sphagetti projects', and I am sure you will agree its a headache trying to optimize something when you are not even sure of the code workflow.